# need help writing code that detects if a file exists or not

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write code that first checks if a file exists or not, then checks if the file is empty, and if not, puts the contents of the file in a list.

If the file does not exist or is empty, it should just return an empty list.  Whenever I tested it by using a file that does not exist, it says it can't find the file, even though I told it that if it couldn't find the file to return an empty string.

Here is my code.

```
import os

def fileToList(fileName):
  
    newList = []
  
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileName)
    fileExist = os.path.exists(fileName)
   
    if fileExist == True:
        if fileSize != 0:
            f = open(fileName,"r")
            for line in f:
                newList.append(line.strip())
            f.close()
            return newList
        else:
            return newList
        
    else:
        return newList
```

Comment: This line `fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileName)` should be placed after the file exists test takes place.  Think about it, if the file does not exist, checking the size will throw an error, yes?

Comment: Maybe you should check if the file exists *before* trying to get its size.

Comment: Just open the file and handle the exception if it was not there!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code gave you an error is this line:

```
fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileName)
```

If the file ceased to exist, you cannot get the size of it.

```
import os

def fileToList(fileName):
    if os.path.exists(fileName) and os.path.getsize(fileName):
        with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
            return f.readlines()
    else:
        return []
    
print(fileToList('random.txt'))
```

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks. Please approve the edit/ on the OP post.

Answer (score 0):

Move the line `fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileName)` to right below `if fileExist == True:` in your code (as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678695/need-help-writing-code-that-detects-if-a-file-exists-or-not/63678828#comment112604969_63678695)), otherwise that will throw an error whenthe file does not exist.

Your modified code would then look like this:

```
import os

def fileToList(fileName):
  
    newList = []
  
    fileExist = os.path.exists(fileName)
   
  
    if fileExist == True:
        fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileName)
        if fileSize != 0:
            f = open(fileName,"r")
            for line in f:
                newList.append(line.strip())
            f.close()
            return newList
        else:
            return newList
        
    else:
        return newList
```

Comment: You can simplify to `if fileExist` and `if fileSize`.  Additionally, the `with open()` convention should be used, and (generally) a function should only have a single `return` statement.